# iOS 11 negative additionalSafeAreaInsets?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I'm trying to cope with the wasted space on iPhone x in landscape mode by using this little trick:

```
func fixSafeArea() {
    guard #available(iOS 11, *) else {
        print("Safe area is not available for non iOS 11 devices.")
        return
    }

    var newSafeArea = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight {
        newSafeArea.left = -20.0
    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft {
        newSafeArea.right = -20.0
    }

    print("Safe area adjusted to \(newSafeArea)")
    self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = newSafeArea
}
```

However negative UIEdgeInsets do not seem to work. Does anyone know how to override the safeArea insets in order to make use of the free screen on wither landscape orientations?

And one more thing: Why didn't apple make this the default behaviour since they put the home "slider" at the bottom? The screen on the opposite side of the top notch is literally wasted using safe areas in landscape

Comment: To answer the last part, Apple believe the UI should be centred, and should appear the same whether in landscape left or landscape right.  See [Designing for iPhone X](https://developer.apple.com/fall17/801) at around 9'20.

Comment: My stab was to remove the safe are layout guide an re-create it, but that's not possible: "You may not remove a system-vended UILayoutGuide from its owning view."

Comment: @JohnScalo I cound't find a way to get this working and decided that "Apple knows best"... So I left it as it is, with big nice wasted space, as everyone seems to be ok with this.

Comment: Ha, yeah thanks for the update. Possibly one remedy would be to remove the safe area guide from the view altogether (e.g. delete it in the storyboard) and then use additionalSafeAreaInsets as needed, although I didn't try that.